# How do I constantly send a username and password to a specific IP address(captive portal)?

Tags: http, authentication, networking

This question is not language specific.

I want to send my username and password as soon I get logged off from the captive portal because many people are using an admin ID (infinite data benefits) in my college and I want to send the http POST packet asap.

So I want to run a piece of code which runs infinitely (as long as I am online) send the username and password and I have absolutely no clue of how to go about it, is there a batch file that I can run? or something else I haven't the slightest clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple python automation problem. Try this:

How I created a Python Bot to automatically log into a Captive Portal by Ritvik Khanna  https://medium.com/p/how-i-created-a-python-bot-to-automatically-log-into-a-captive-portal-3d4ba04dee9f